# Show two different plots in one plot

Tags: matlab

I am working with Matcont in Matlab and I have a problem with plotting. I am using a special built-in function of Matcont to plot and I would like to display two separate plots in one.

In mathematica I would use the show function.

```
a=cpl(x,v,s,[4 1])
b=cpl(x1,v1,s1,[4 1])
Show[{a, b}]
```

I am looking for the same [Show](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) function in matlab.

Comment: Sounds like you're after [`hold on`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Dan already mentioned in the comments, it seems like you try to do something like this:

```
a=1:10
b=a.^2

plot(a)
hold on
plot(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Learning Subplots

In matlab this is done using the `subplot` function.
[Here is the reference.](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html)

Basically you first create a figure, then divide it into a 2-D grid using the first two arguments to subplot:

```matlab
subplot(2, 2, 1);
```

for example would create a 2-by-2 grid -- thus creating space for 4 plots. The last index `1` selects the first plot of the grid, i.e. the plot in position (0, 0) starting from the top left corner of the figure area.

```matlab
subplot(2, 2, 3);
```

Would instead select the third plot, i.e. the plot in position (1, 0) starting from the top left corner of the figure area.

### A Working Example

A working example in your case would be

```matlab
figure(1); % Create new figure #1
clf; % Clear the figure

% Compute the data
a=cpl(x,v,s,[4 1])
b=cpl(x1,v1,s1,[4 1])

% Plot it
subplot(2, 1, 1);
plot(a);

subplot(2, 1, 2);
plot(b);
```

---

## Learning to Hold On

If, as others mentioned, you are instead trying to plot two curves on the same pair of axes, the [hold](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) function is what you need. Without the hold your second plot command would in fact overwrite the first plot.

### A Working Example

A working example in your case would be

```matlab
figure(1); % Create new figure #1
clf; % Clear the figure

% Compute the data
a=cpl(x,v,s,[4 1])
b=cpl(x1,v1,s1,[4 1])

% Plot it
plot(a);
hold on;
plot(b);
```

Comment: After reading the documentation of mathematica's `show`, I think this is more complicated then what the asker needs. (You explain how to make 2 plots, whilst it appears he is looking to make a plot with multiple lines)

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Ach! I wasted time then. :)