# Plot multiple data matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

Good Morning, I have a problem with matlab plot.

I have generated sample of data that belong to different days; the data are the main posture of the human (labelled with 1,2,3,4).

Now I have 30 vector (one for each day) with the number of sample equals to the seconds of the day (about 86400 sample...). I have one posture for each second.

My aim is to plot the distribution of the sample during one month, in X axis I would have the days of the month (1,2,3.....30) and in the Y axis I would have the hour (sample/3600 I think).

How can I plot all the data in only one graph? I have two main problem:

- I have 30 vector with different lenght (because I have generated the sample with random function) so the first step is to allineate the data I think because PLOT function needs vectors with the same lenght...
- plot 30 days in the same plot, in order to evaluate the whole distribution of the posture in a month

A small example: day1 = [2222111333444] day2 = [22111333333444] day3 = [2221111133334444]. The input are sequences of postures (one sequence for day); now I need to obtain a plot with a "vertical representation" of these postures (on the x axis the days, on the y axis the hour of the day, for each hour I have about 3600 sample-one sample for second). With the command "hold on" no problem but I don't need to overlap the data but I need to place side by side the vector data

Andrea

Comment: Please do [include a minimum complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show you actually attempted a solution. On a different note, plot needs vectors of equal lengths only if you call it like this: `plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2])`. You can however `hold` between plot commands and these need not to be plots of vectors of same length. See [this answer on a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530541/show-two-different-plots-in-one-plot/26530584#26530584) for more info.

Comment: Modify your question rather than adding stuff in comments. Comments are just for that: comments. ;)

Comment: You write "Now I have 30 vector (one for each day) with the number of sample equals to the seconds of the day" and later: "I have 30 vector with different lenght (because I have generated the sample with random function) " not clear what is ment. Also: The values in your vector day1= [2,4,5,...] mean, that at second 1, a value of 2 should be plotted and at second 2 a value of 4 has to be plotted. This would create a 3d plot?

Answer (score 1):

It goes something like this, but of course,if you have 30 days and one entry per second you would need to use a matrix and sum the individual rows. Also, you don't need to make the vectors the same size, but then you have to use a different parameter for the x axis (Days) everytime.

```
day1=[2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 4 4 4]; 
day2=[2 2 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4];
day3=[2 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 4 4 4 4 4 4];

Days=1:3;

LayingTime=[sum(day1==1),sum(day2==1),sum(day3==1)];
SittingTime=[sum(day1==2),sum(day2==2),sum(day3==2)];
StandingTime=[sum(day1==3),sum(day2==3),sum(day3==3)];
RockingTime=[sum(day1==4),sum(day2==4),sum(day3==4)];

plot(Days,LayingTime,Days,SittingTime,Days,StandingTime,Days,RockingTime)

xlabel('Day')
ylabel('Hours of Activity')
legend('Hours Laying','Hours Sitting','Hours Standing','Hours Rocking')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response...; Specifically, I don't need the total hours of activity for lying down, standing, etc... but the distribution during the day (my input vector could be 1112232224444333222 etc...); I need to display the interval time od the activity, example If in the day 1 The user sleeps (lying posture) from 22 P.M to 6 A.M. and in the day 2 he sleeps from 22.30 to 6.30 for example

Comment: So the Y axis would be 24h and it would map what he did in every hour?

Comment: Hmmm... I can only think about using `contourf()` like this  `Z=[day1',day2',day3']; contourf(Z,3)`. Might give you something good enough if your activities are continuos(i.e. no jumps 2<->4 or 1<->4)... try it.

Comment: Ok, I try this technique....actually I plot a matrix with the command Image